# Get an access token to Linkedin API using email and password

Tags: node.js, access-token, linkedin-api

Is it possible to get an access token in order to use node-linkedin package by providing credentials - user email and password? What I'm trying to do is an command line app, that can make an api calls to linkedin and write results in a text file. Thus, I'm not sending any api call results to the client.

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying to do the same thing.

the `simple-oauth2` module has a method for logging in via password, but I cannot seem to get it to work.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-oauth2

```
// Set the configuration settings
const credentials = {
  client: {
    id: '<client-id>',
    secret: '<client-secret>'
  },
  auth: {
    tokenHost: 'https://api.linkedin.com',
    authorizePath: 'https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken',
    tokenPath: 'https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/accessToken'
  }
};

// Initialize the OAuth2 Library
const oauth2 = require('simple-oauth2').create(credentials);

// Get the access token object.
const tokenConfig = {
  username: 'username',
  password: 'password' 
};

// Callbacks
// Save the access token
oauth2.ownerPassword.getToken(tokenConfig, (error, result) => {
  if (error) {
    return console.log('Access Token Error', error.message);
  }

  const token = oauth2.accessToken.create(result);
});
```

I am not sure these endpoints are correct:

```
  auth: {
    tokenHost: 'https://api.linkedin.com',
    authorizePath: 'https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken',
    tokenPath: 'https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/accessToken'
  }
```

I get a 400 bad request.

Comment: thanks for the answer! currently I can't reproduce this, so if anyone finds this answer useful I'll mark it as the most helpful!

Comment: actually it is impossible for me to check it out, so your answer works as expected for you and resolves my problem, I will mark you answer as accepted.